# How to store historical value of a raster pixel in postgis raster datatype?

Tags: raster, postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster

I have a postgres table to store rasters having elevation value in each pixels. the raster size on average is around 100x100 with scale of 1. The elevation value is historic and I store timestamp in band 1 and elevation value in band 2

I need to store this historical value in the same raster as and when I receive data instead of creating new raster. This is to avoid multiple rasters in the same table created over period of time. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

No - if you were to find a *practical* way to en- and decode arbitrary numeric values within a single, *practically sized*¹ numerical representation (i.e. the bit-range of the common data types), or find a way around the limitations of spline and polynominal *interpolation* for functional representation, you'd be a Nobel prize money billionaire.

---

However, you *could* simply abstract your time series into raster bands:

- add a new band with a time bin as close as possible to the interval range in which you are receiving updates; e.g. one band per day/week/month/year
- encode the EPOCH seconds and the height value in a `64BF` pixel value - you will have 16 digits available to do so: 17 digits considered for output, minus one to avoid floating point rounding errors, e.g.:

  ```
  [-/+]hhhhhh.ssssssssss[x]
  ```

  with

  - `[+/-]hhhhhh`: *height [cm]*
  - `ssssssssss`: *timestamp in EPOCH seconds*
  - `[x]`: *unused digit to avoid rounding issues*

---

¹ *Mathematically*, you can encode any *finite* range of numbers consecutively within a single number, with plenty of means - but in any case, this number would have an *obscene* amount of digits (think millions) *very* quickly...

Comment: I got ur answer of the approach is not feasible straightforward and only work arounds are available. Thanks